# Dynamicly Fill Array From Table at PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i need to pass array values dynamic at this PL/SQL CODE But the Array Just See The First Value the code  : Hint( The code is big so i cut it at the issue part)please

if you need more information Kindly Ask me,Here is my try to pass it Dynamic.

Variable fill code:

```
FOR ET IN (SELECT   EMAIL
               FROM   XX_INTERCO_SYS_CON
              WHERE   ACC_NO = Q.ACC_NO AND TYPE = 'TO')
  LOOP
     IF P_TO IS NOT NULL
     THEN
        P_TO := P_TO || ',''' || ET.EMAIL||'''';
     ELSE
        P_TO := ''''||ET.EMAIL||'''';
     END IF;
  END LOOP;

  FOR EC IN (SELECT   EMAIL
               FROM   XX_INTERCO_SYS_CON
              WHERE   ACC_NO = Q.ACC_NO AND TYPE = 'CC')
  LOOP
     IF P_CC IS NOT NULL
     THEN
        P_CC := P_CC || ',''' || EC.EMAIL||'''';
     ELSE
        P_CC := ''''||EC.EMAIL||'''';
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

The Array fill part :

```
XX_MAIL_PKG.SEND (P_FROM        => P_FROM,
                    P_TO          => XX_MAIL_PKG.ARRAY ( P_TO),
                    P_CC          => XX_MAIL_PKG.ARRAY (P_CC),
                    P_SUBJECT     => 'test',
                    P_HTML_MSG    => P_HTML_OUTPUT,
                    P_SMTP_HOST   => P_SMTP_HOST,
                    P_SMTP_PORT   => P_SMTP_PORT,
                    P_TEXT_MSG    => NULL,
                    X_ERR_MSG     => X_ERR_MSG);
  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (X_ERR_MSG);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using collections - so (without knowing what is in the `XX_MAIL_PKG` package) you could try this:

```
DECLARE
  V_TO XX_MAIL_PKG.ARRAY;
  V_CC XX_MAIL_PKG.ARRAY;
BEGIN
  SELECT EMAIL
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_TO
  FROM   XX_INTERCO_SYS_CON
  WHERE  ACC_NO = Q.ACC_NO AND TYPE = 'TO';

  SELECT EMAIL
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_CC
  FROM   XX_INTERCO_SYS_CON
  WHERE  ACC_NO = Q.ACC_NO AND TYPE = 'CC';

  XX_MAIL_PKG.SEND (P_FROM        => P_FROM,
                    P_TO          => V_TO,
                    P_CC          => V_CC,
                    P_SUBJECT     => 'test',
                    P_HTML_MSG    => P_HTML_OUTPUT,
                    P_SMTP_HOST   => P_SMTP_HOST,
                    P_SMTP_PORT   => P_SMTP_PORT,
                    P_TEXT_MSG    => NULL,
                    X_ERR_MSG     => X_ERR_MSG);
  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (X_ERR_MSG);
END;
/
```

Comment: I'm Very Very Thankful for your big deeds it works like charm your fast replay was very kind from you